# Java using regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I am working with resetting passwords.  I need a way in java using regular expressions to reset the password so it cannot contain 4 consecutive characters from the previous password.

Comment: you need to write a function that saves the old password as String and write your regular expression string according to that...is that right?that's what you need? This may help : http://www.wellho.net/regex/java.html

Comment: this would need to store passwords in plain text. Don't.

Comment: @Samuel_xL Generally when changing passwords you need to enter the previous one first. That means both are available at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that regular expression is an apropriate tool for this task.

Actually, I can't see any other solution then a loop which will try to find a substring of 4 common characters.

Comment: check out my answer. Quite succint and readable, and uses only basic regex components.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions isn't solution to every world problem. You code would be much simpler and clearer if you implemented this as normal loop with 'indexOf' check.

**edit**
I'm assuming you plan to use it in some application. If you ask just out of curiosity, then I don't know :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to build that dynamically.  Say you have a previous password of 'tiddlywinks'.  That would mean the following are not allowed:

tidd
iddl
ddly
dlyw
lywi
ywin
inks

Just so happens it's nice and ends on a 4 character boundary.  Didn't plan that one.  Anyway.  Walk through your previous password like so:

```
public Pattern toValidationExpression( String previousPassword ) {
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   for( int i = 0; i < previousPassword.length()-4; i++ ) {
      if( i > 0 ) builder.append( "|" );
      builder.append( "(" );
      builder.append( previousPassword.substring(i, Math.min( i+4, previousPassword.length() );
      builder.append( ")" );
   }
   return Pattern.compile( builder.toString() );
}
```

Comment: Just a comment, I didn't look at your code, but you missed "wink" and it will always end on a "boundary," as you're incrementing by one, not four :-)

Comment: Thanks so much!!  With your code I got exactly what I needed.  Its working!!  :)

Comment: @LordArtemis You are right that my example I typed should have wink in the list.

Answer (score 1):

With some reasonable restrictions, this can in fact be done quite easily with regex.

Assuming that `\n` is an illegal part of the password (VERY reasonable restriction), then the following code will do the check quite readably (if you know how to read regex):

```
static boolean legalChange(String before, String after) {
    String joined = String.format("%s\n%s", before, after);
    return !joined.matches(".*(.{4}).*\n.*\\1.*");
}
```

Here's a test harness ([see also on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/KCV72)):

```
    String[][] tests = {
        { "abcdef", "ghijklm" },                // true
        { "abcdef", "xbcdeyz" },                // false
        { "abcdef", "fedbcda" },                // true
        { "xyz", "" },                          // true
        { "0123456789", "abc123def456ghi" },    // true
        { "0123456789", "abc123456ghi" },       // false
    };
    for (String[] test : tests) {
        System.out.println(legalChange(test[0], test[1]));
    }
```

Note that this regex only checks for the "no common substring of length 4" rule. Additional password regex rules must also be in place.

---

#### How it works

Essentially we combine the two strings into one, delimited by `\n` (which again is an illegal character to have in usernames anyway).

This regex, then, will match an *ILLEGAL* change:

```
   before | after              i.e. before = .* (.{4}) .*
          |                         after  = .*   \1   .*
.*(.{4}).*\n.*\1.*
  \____/
    1
```

That is, we match and capture `(.{4})` from `before` into group 1, and use backreference `\1` to see if it can be matched in `after`. We put `.*` around those two to allow the occurrence to happen anywhere. The regex engine will do all the necessary backtracking on the `.*` to see if this pattern can match.

Since that pattern matches an *ILLEGAL* change, we negate the result of `matches` with the `boolean` complement operator `!`.

This is not the most efficient solution for the problem, but assuming that passwords are of reasonable length, speed will not be an issue.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Dot Matches (Almost) Any Character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), [Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), [Grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: well, I like it, mostly because I like regular expressions :). But it looks like some magic if you aren't experienced in regexp. +1 for the `String.format`, I didn't know this elegant way of string concatenation but will use it from now.

Answer (score 0):

So, lets assume you are using char[] instead of String to store old/new passwords to be **somewhat** safe.  Security experts have better tools...encryption/hashing/etc... for password management.

So, here goes:

```
/**
 * Compare old to new password to a repeating 4char sequence.
 * -> require passNew to be >= 4char sequence, else return false.
 * -> require passOld to be >= 4char sequence, else return true.
 * -> utilize shifting long to handle full 16Bit char range.
 * -> does not support char beyond 16Bit char range... e.g. codepoint > 2^16.
 * -> codepoint > 2^16 support could be done with XOR 4 codepoints with 8bit shifts
 * @return success true if passNew >= 4char sequence,
 *    passOld lessthan 4char sequence or
 *    normal... 4char sequence not found.
 */
public final boolean validatePassword(char[] passOld, char[] passNew) {
    if (passNew.length lessthan 4) {
        return (false);
    } else if (passOld lessthan 4) {
        return (true);
    }
    long patOld = ((passOld[0] & 0x0ffL) leftshift 32) |
        ((passOld[1] & 0x0ffL) leftshift 16) |
        (passOld[2] & 0x0ffL);
    long patNewOrig = ((passNew[0] & 0x0ffL) leftshift 32) |
        ((passNew[1] & 0x0ffL) leftshift 16) |
        (passNew[2] & 0x0ffL);
    long patNew;
    int offOld = 2, lenOld = passOld.length
    int offNew = 2, lenNew = passNew.length;
    while (++offOld lessthan lenOld) {
        patOld = (patOld leftshift 16) | (passOld[offOld] & 0x0ffL);
        patNew = patNewOrig;
        offNew = 2;
        while (++offNew lessthan lenNew) {
            patNew = (patNew leftshift 16) | (passNew[offNew] & 0x0ffL);
            if (patOld == patNew) {
                return (false);
            }
        }
    }
    return (true);
}
```